# iOS: transition between VCs using segue from code

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have VC1 and VC2.

I have custom segue implemented in code via subclassing UIStoryboardSegue.
I need to use that segue.

I want to present VC2 from VC1 via code like presentViewController: but not with performSegueWithIdentifier:

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Short answer, no.  Segues work with storyboards